# Increase num_ordered in order_line for all GME category parts by 20%

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

This is a homework problem, but I am stumped.  I know that this would involve two different tables:  order_line and item, because 'num_ordered' is in order_line and 'category' is in item.  I also know:  1) this will involve an 'update', 2) there will have to be a function involved:  (round(sum(num_ordered * 1.20)),0)--this will increase num_ordered by 20% & will round up to a whole number, and 3) I know that there will have to be a 'set' for num_ordered.  What I do not know is how to make the update work with a function involved. This is my current code that does not work:

```
update order_line ol
inner join
    (select i.item_num,(round(sum(ol.num_ordered * 1.20)),0) new_num
    from i.item
    where category = 'GME'
    group by i.item_num)
on ol.item_num = og.item_num
set ol.num_ordered  = og.new_num;
```

Comment: Please include a [MCVE] with the full text of the actual question (rather than trying to make us guess what the question is from your assumptions about the question) and the DDL statements for the tables involved. Also note that, by the StackOverflow license, contributions here are [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) and you will need to cite any answers used when you submit your homework.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you only need to test for existence. If the item on the order line belongs to the set of items in category 'GME'.

```
update order_line ol
   set ol.num_ordered = ol.num_ordered * 1.2
 where ol.item_num in(
         select i.item_num
           from item i
          where i.category = 'GME');
```

Comment: You either need to remove the `i.` prefixes (and the `ol` alias is also unnecessary) or change `from i.item` to `from item i`.

Comment: Thanks, I spotted the same mistake myself in the original question but then I forgot to fix it :)